# Permanently set file and folder permission for a user

Tags: permissions, users

I just got hold of a Linux machine running Ubuntu from my friend. It places 644 permission on all new files created by a user.

But for some purposes I want 755 permission on all files and folder created by that user, I have been searching on Internet from all day long but did not got hold of any useful resources plus I am a beginner to Linux system as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the .profile of that user or in the global `/etc/profile`, put

```
umask 027
```

Note to self: to get the umask, subtract the desired directory octal permissions from 777, so in that case 777-750 becomes 027. This should give `drwxr-x---`.

With that umask, the file creation mask will be 666-027 = 640 (note that this is not real subtraction, you subtract digit by digit); this will give `-rw-r-----`.

In short: you can read, write and change into directories; group can read and change into directories; anyone else is blocked. Is that correct?

Comment: it does not help, I already tried this. It makes permission to be this `-----w--w-`

Comment: Silly me, forgot to subtract the chmod value from 777.

Comment: I also just figured out the same, but is it not possible to have both directory and files a 755 permission. As far as I got, with umask files never get an execute permission.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your question properly. Sorry, you are right, I don't think that's possible.