# Change default permission 664 for downloaded files

Tags: 14.04, permissions

I have noticed that all downloaded files, either via Firefox or `wget` get permission of 664 (`rw-rw-r--`). This makes me run additional step via `chmod` when I want to **use** **these files** via another tool, like Gimp.

Is there a way that I change this permission to 774?

Comment: Gimp don't need more permissions than `644`

Comment: @A.B. Yes it does for plugins

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanently set file and folder permission for a user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190176/permanently-set-file-and-folder-permission-for-a-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** change that. No file that you load from the Internet should be executable by default. This is a too high security risk.

If you really want this … [Permanently set file and folder permission for a user](https://askubuntu.com/q/190176/367165)

---

If you want to execute the file, you should **always** change the rights manually. No editing application needs rights to execute a file. Especially no image editing program. In the case of plugins, read the part above again. **;)**

Comment: +1 for the general idea, but if I run `ls -l` on the (freshly downloaded) eclipse executable: `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: @JacobVlijm Hmm, that's bad :\